# Failed when install bit in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, terminal, bit.dev

I went to install bit.dev and received the error below in the terminal

```
npx @teambit/bvm install
√ downloading version 1.2.7 in 10 minutes, 5.377 seconds
| extracting version 1.2.7 using child-process methodfailed to extract, error:  Command failed with exit code 1: tar -xf bit-1.2.7-win-x64.tar.gz
bit-1.2.7/node_modules/global-prefix/node_modules/.bin/which: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.bvm\temp\bit-1.2.7\node_modules\global-prefix\node_modules\.bin\which': Invalid argument
```

Other `bit-1.2.7/node_modules` is error as the same

I'm using
`node v18.18.2`
`npm 8.12.1`

Its weird since i install it perfectly fine on other machine with the same node and npm version, is there any clue to fix it?

Comment: Did you run it in powershell or cmd? And can you run it under administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and comment from @Ashan, I figured out I need to run as Administrator on cmd or PowerShell to have permission to install on `Admin\AppData`.